# how to record html requests

Tags: c++, network-programming, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I want to record html request being sent and received by a browser ( firefox as an example ).My aim is to make a tool for load testing. So if I can capture all request being sent from my browser then I can play the same links without browser with the help of some code ( c++ ). So wireshark is there that captures all packets being sent through network card.But it will be very complicated because wireshark only record all packets being sent by the machine ( if a gtalk is running it will capture those packets as well ).
suppose I have a c++ code that will open a browser with a url called www.google.com.
So now by my c++ code one browser will open . Then whatever i will search through my browser those http / https requests i want to store in some file. I mainly want to make an interface for browser that will captures http / https urls and will save it in some packet. want to store the url not the corresponding IP for the url.

I want to design whole the things using c / c++ .

Thank you .

Comment: Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Use a firefox extension such as httpfox.